# Listbox Selected property causes problems

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have a listbox in a Diagram, when calling the function "drawDiagram" I want to get the selected Items of the listbox. Here is my code to do that:

```
Function DrawDiagram()
Dim x As Integer
Dim diaLst As ListBox
Set diaLst = ActiveSheet.ListBoxes("DiaList")

' find selected trends in List Box
For x = 0 To diaLst.ListCount - 1
    If diaLst.Selected(x) = True Then
        MsgBox x
    End If
Next x
End Function
```

diaLst.ListCount correctly returns the number of Items in the list. But diaLst.Selected(x) does not work at all.

The Error message is:
German: "Die Selected-Eigenschaft des ListBox-Objektes kann nicht zugeordent werden"
English: "The Selected Property of the ListBox Object cannot be assigned" (or similar)

Does anyone know, what I did wrong?

thanks
natasia

Comment: What happens if you try and print out diaLst.ListIndex? Or diaLst.List(diaLst.ListIndex)?

Comment: does not work also.

Comment: Try along with dim dialist as object, instead of list box.

Comment: This does not work too :(

Answer (score 0):

first off, you must be dealing with a "Form" control (not an "ActiveX" one) otherwise you couldn't get it via `.ListBoxes` property of `Worksheet` class

I tested it in my environment (W7-Pro and Excel 2013) and found that (quite strangely to me) the `Selected()` property array is 1-based.

This remained even with `Option Base 0` at the beginning of the module

Make sure Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library reference is added to your project

```
Function DrawDiagram()
    Dim x As Long
    Dim diaLst As MSForms.ListBox

    Set diaLst = ActiveSheet.ListBoxes("DiaList")

    ' find selected trends in List Box
    For x = 1 To diaLst.ListCount
        If diaLst.Selected(x) = True Then
            MsgBox x
        End If
    Next x
End Function
```

Comment: yes the function is not returning anything. It is not finished yet. 

Actually, I do not know what you mean by "dealing with a From control, not an ActiveX". But, I am able to get the listbox by the .ListBoxes property of the Worksheet. Nevertheless I am not able to use the Selected property in any way. In contrast I can use the addItem property without any problems.

Comment: Unfortunatly no. Before I programmed the sub/function above, I did a Userform with almost the same code. Just wrote instead of diaLst Me.Listbox. That worked fine. I really do not know why this does not work. It seems that diaLst does not have the full property list of a listbox. But why this happens I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, this is the code I used to generate the list box in a chart sheet, in a separate function. At the moment when a button is clicked, the DrawDiagram function is called. The aim of the "DrawDiagram" function is to plot the selected items of the listbox in the diagram.

```
Set diaLst = ActiveSheet.ListBoxes.Add(ActiveChart.ChartArea.Width - 110, 5, 105, 150)
With diaLst
    .Name = "DiaList"
    .PrintObject = False
    .MultiSelect = xlSimple

    i = 2
    While wTD.Cells(rowVarNames, i) <> ""
        .AddItem wTD.Cells(rowVarNames, i)
        i = i + 1
    Wend
    .Selected(3) = True
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

use Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("List Box 1").OLEFormat.Object instead

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same problem. The solution turned out to be simple, just had to tweak the code a litte bit and play around with the ListBox properites:

```
Function GetSelectedRowsFromListBox(lstbox As ListBox) As Collection

    Create the collection
    Dim coll As New Collection
    Dim lst_cnt As Variant
    lst_cnt = lstbox.ListCount
    Dim arr_selectedVal As Variant
    arr_selectedVal = lstbox.Selected
    ' Read through each item in the listbox
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To lstbox.ListCount
    
        ' Check if item at position i is selected
        If arr_selectedVal(i) Then
            coll.Add i
        End If
    Next i

    Set GetSelectedRowsFromListBox = coll

End Function
```

.Selected property returns a 1-based array with True/False values coresponding to rows in your multiple choice Form Control ListBox.

From that you can get the list of each value.

This solution is an expanded version of what is mentioned here, however this also complies with Form Control ListBox, no just ActiveX ListBox (which are 2 same but different things ;) ):
https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-listbox/

Hope that helps in the future!